# fatal error: Rcpp.h: No such file or directory

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm just trying to get started with Rcpp and I keep running into this error no matter what I do.

```
> library("Rcpp")
> evalCpp("2 + 2")
"C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"//ad.uws.edu.au/dfshare/HomesBLK90946112/My Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/90946112/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0Q7m7J/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-1.0.5"        -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c file45bc2c9438a5.cpp -o file45bc2c9438a5.o
file45bc2c9438a5.cpp:1:10: fatal error: Rcpp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Rcpp.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:229: file45bc2c9438a5.o] Error 1
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

To check that everything is set up correctly, I have run the following checks:

```
> find_rtools()
[1] TRUE
> find.package('Rcpp')
[1] "\\\\ad.uws.edu.au/dfshare/HomesBLK$/90946112/My Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp"
```

and

```
> find_rtools()
[1] TRUE
> find.package('Rcpp')
[1] "\\\\ad.uws.edu.au/dfshare/HomesBLK$/90946112/My Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp"
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.0.2\\bin\\x64;C:\\Rtools\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\90946112\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;"
> has_devel()
Your system is ready to build packages!
```

I've seen so many questions on here for similar problems but none for Rtools40- which has a different file path- and none have helped. I have tried using an older version of R and Rtools. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled both.

Please help!

Comment: You're compiling with `-I"//ad.uws.edu.au/dfshare/HomesBLK90946112/My Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/include"` whereas the header file is at `"\\\\ad.uws.edu.au/dfshare/HomesBLK$/90946112/My Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp"`. Those are not quite the same thing (look around the $ sign). Unless this got mangled while you were copy-pasting it here, that could very well be the source of your problem.

Comment: Oh ok! Can you help me correct this? I don't recall copying anything to assign these pathways- I believe they were detected automatically.

Comment: Assuming this is indeed the problem and the tool that you use for building does not support '$'. Then you have the option of fixing the tool (probably not), using a different tool or moving the library somewhere else that does not have '$' in the path. No idea which option is the most practical for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted! Thanks to @dratenik for the help.

I uninstalled the Rcpp package, ran RStudio as administrator, reinstalled Rcpp in a library that had no special characters, and it runs fine now.